# Regex to allow only number and single dot on android device

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angular, regex

I have my angular application and has HTML template below:

```
 <input inputmode="numeric" id="amount1">
  <input inputmode="decimal" id="amount2">
```

now for the first field, I want to allow only numbers and for the second field, I want to allow `numbers + a single dot` on an `android device`.

In my `directive,` I have below `@HostListner` event

```
@HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event) {
    const regex = /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/;
    const text = event.target.value;  
    if (!text.match(regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

but this does not work for android devices it also allows other special characters, on the web I have a `keyCode`-based solution that recognizes key ranges and that is not the right solution I believe because the android devices will have different `keycodes`.

So, I want a `regex-based` solution that works both on the web and on the android app as well.

Comment: If one copy/pastes a value into your field, how is your `"keypress"` supposed to trigger?

Comment: yeah, I know that, that we will take care of at a later stage. as of now the only thing I am looking is not to allow the special character or "." in case first field and in second field allow only single dot and numeric value only